# How to integrate mixpanel to django backend

Tags: django

I am new with integrating mixpanel to Django backend to track events,As i try to track, it gives me empty brackets anyone with ideas or resources please help me am quite stack

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View
from rest_framework.generics import  ListCreateAPIView
from rest_framework.views import  APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serialize import UserSerializer, TweakSerializer, ChannelSerializer, SubscriberSerializer
from tweaks.models import Tweak
from accounts.models import User
from channels.models import Channel, Subscriber
from mixpanel import Mixpanel

import json


# Create your views here.
mp = Mixpanel('TOKEN')
class userApi(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        
        return Response(serializer.data)
    


apiuser=userApi()
point = json.dumps(apiuser.__dict__)

mp.track(point, 'users')
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from django.urls import path, include
from accounts.models import User
from tweaks.models import Tweak
from channels.models import Channel, Subscriber


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_joined'
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an an old question.But for any one who comes encounter same problem.The mixpanel documentation indicates that you must set user_id as the first parameter. Refer to their documentation [Here](https://docs.mixpanel.com/docs/tracking/reference/python)